# How to modify a local variable in the worker of a running thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I would like to modify a local variable of the `target` worker of a running thread:

```
import threading
import time

def worker():
    a = 1
    while True:
        print(a)
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
# here I would like to modify a in thread t and set it to 2
t.join()
#
# the expected output would be approximately
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 1
# 2
# 2
# ...
```

How can I access (and modify) `a` in thread `t`?

Comment: You can't. Imagine what kind of nightmare would the ability to modify local variables of functions bring upon this cursed land! Say, the function is calculating the length of a string, and then another thread comes in, messes with the function's local variables and thus makes the function return whatever nonsense it likes.

Answer (score 3):

In short "you can't". However, you can redesign your code to allow this to occur. Although I will put a warning, here be dragons.

To be able to modify `a` it needs to be accessible, the best approach is to have an object associated with the thread that holds the variable you want to modify.

```
import threading
import time

# Use a thread class to hold any extra variables we want.
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Store the value of a
        self._a = a

        # Create a lock so thread access is synchronised
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    # Use a property to control access to a via our lock
    @property
    def a(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        with self.lock:
            self._a = value

    # Your origional worker method
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(self.a)
            time.sleep(1)

# The thread can now be instantiated 
t = WorkerThread(1)
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
# And your value modified.
t.a = 2
time.sleep(5)
t.join()
```

Note though that using `join` does not stop the thread, it just waits for it to finish.

Comment: +1 for that comment on `join`. Just recently I needed a few moments to understand why my program never terminates with a similar scenario...

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the thread's local variable. Instead, use a global variable for this task:

```
import threading
import time

a = 1

def worker():
    while True:
        print(a)
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
a = 2
t.join()
```

Comment: You should not be modifying variables cross-thread without locks!

Comment: Python has Global Interpreter Lock which takes care of it when global variables are shared among various threads.

Comment: If you are using CPython, yes for certain operations. But that may not be the case for all implementations.